# Class not recognized - laravel Eloquent Model

Tags: php, class, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-routing

I am trying to update my database using Eloquent model but the class is not recognized.

First I created my table using migration and that worked fine.. Below is the code
    use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
    use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

```
class CreatePaintings extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
 public function up()
 {
    Schema::create('paintings',function($thepainting){
            $thepainting->increments('id');
            $thepainting->string('title');
            $thepainting->string('artist');
            $thepainting->integer('year');
            $thepainting->timestamps();

    });
 }

 /**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('paintings');
}
}
```

Next, I created a class "paint" using the model. But note that the recent version of laravel don't have the model folder specified explicitly. So when I ran the code below on the command prompt I was able to create the paint class

```
php artisan make:model paint
```

Lastly, I tried updating the created table, paintings, via routes.php using the code below..

```
Route::get('/', function() 
{
$paintings = new Paint;
$paintings->title = 'Emmanuel';
$paintings->artist = 'D. DoRight';
$painitngs->year = 2014;
$paintings->save();

return view('trynn');

});


 Route::get('about/directions', function() 
 {
 return "Direction content goes here";
  });

 Route::get('about/{theSubject}', function($theSubject) 
  {  
  return $theSubject. " content goes here";

  });
```

please I am new to laravel, so I will appreciate any help to get this resolved. I am presently stranded. Lest I forget, The error message is shown below

---

Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

1/1
FatalErrorException in routes.php line 18:
Class 'Paint' not found

### in routes.php line 18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, this is a simple error. Can you copy-paste the whole content of the file in if that is not all of it.

Also the error for this is because you haven't brought in the class from the autoloader. In Laravel, everything is namespaced. In your Paint Model, at the top you will see `namespace App`, if you moved the Paint model into say a models directory, you need to namespace the class `App\Models;`

To fix this error, at the top of the `routes.php` file, write `use App\Paint;`. But you should really send that route to a controller to separate the code from the routes.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks a whole lot..But after adding "use App\paint" .. It showed another error stating the "paints" is not included in the database, considering the class name I used was paint. So I changed the class name to painting, since I stored my table name with the name "paintings".. Once again, Thank you, I'm grateful

Comment: Ah no problem, glad to help. Quick tip, laravels models have a `$table` property. So if your table name was `paintings` and your model name was `paint`, in your `paint` model you could have added `protected $table = 'paintings';`

Answer (score 0):

it's normal the class Pain not found, check what you done here :

```
php artisan make:model paint
```

and on your routes file :

```
$paintings = new Paint;
```

try to correct your model class name to this **Paint** , and when you want to instanciate it don't forget the namespace by default for the generated model class , so you routes file will look like this

```
Route::get('/', function() 
{
      $paintings = new App\Paint;
      $paintings->title = 'Emmanuel';
      $paintings->artist = 'D. DoRight';
      $painitngs->year = 2014;
      $paintings->save();
      return view('trynn');

});
```